# Help with an exercise 17 of chapter 10, in Lang's *Algebra*.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The problem in question is exercise 17 of chapter 10.

> Let $0\rightarrow K^1\rightarrow \cdot\cdot\cdot \rightarrow K^n\rightarrow 0$ be a complex of finite free modules over a local
> Noetherian ring $A$ without nilpotent elements. For each prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ and module $E$,
> let $E(\mathfrak{p}) = E_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}E\mathfrak{p}$, and similarly let $K(\mathfrak{p})$ be the complex localized and reduced mod $\mathfrak{p}$.
> For a given integer $i$, assume that \begin{equation}\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})} H^i(K(\mathfrak{p}))\end{equation}
> is constant, where $H^i$ is the $i$-th homology of the reduced complex. Show that $H^i(K)$
> is free and that we have a natural isomorphism \begin{equation}H^i(K)(\mathfrak{p})\xrightarrow{\sim}H^i(K(\mathfrak{p}))\end{equation}
> [Hint: First write $d_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ for the map induced by $d^i$ on $K^i(\mathfrak{p})$. Write
> \begin{equation}\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})} \text{Ker}\, d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})} = \text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})} K^i(\mathfrak{p}) - \text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})}\text{Im}\,d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})}\end{equation}
> Then show that the dimensions $\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})}\text{Im}\,d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ and $\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})}\text{Im}\,d^{i-1}_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ must be constant.
> Then apply Exercise 12.]

I believe the "Apply exercise 12" in the hint is a typo, because the only exercise that seems relevant here is Exercise 16 of the chapter. I think the problem works out applying the results of that, given that $\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})}\text{Im}\,d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is constant. But this I have not been able to prove, no matter what I try. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Here is what I have so far, although I really have very little progress:

The problem works out if I can prove that $\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})}\text{Im}\,d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is constant, because a previous exercise says that the quotient of the range by the image of the homorphism is then free. I can restrict the range of the homomorphism to $\text{Ker}\,d^{i+1}$, and that the resulting quotient is free is exactly what I have been asked to show.

However, I have been able to make next to no progress in trying to show that $\text{dim}_{k(\mathfrak{p})}\text{Im}\,d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is constant. I can show that each $\text{Im}\,d^i_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is free because it's a direct summand of $K^i(p)$, but I'm not sure if the constant dimension follows, so I think this is the wrong approach. I'm not asking for a full solution, just a pointer in the right direction would help.

Comment: Are you asking that we solve it for you?  That's not what we do here; we prefer to see more investment of effort on you part.  We all volunteer on this site. The least we ask is that you put as much effort into asking, that we put into answering. Please expand on what you've tried, including the steps until you get stuck.

Comment: @amwhy I understand your point, and I have added edits, but I really have no idea where to start.